# How to store files with current date / Sys.Date() in R?

Tags: r, date

Each day I do slightly different graphs or analysis. I don't use `git`. I would like to use a time stamp for version control in my file names. Instead of saving a graph or table like this:

```
data(sleep)

myplot <- qplot(x = group, y = extra, data=sleep)

png(file="myplot.png", width=600, height=350)
myplot
dev.off()
```

I am looking for something like this:

```
png(file=paste0("myplot" + as.character(Sys.Date()) + ".png"), width=600, height=350)
myplot
dev.off()
```

Any help with the paste is appreciated.

Comment: Your approach is correct. You need `,` instead of `+`. `png(file=paste0("myplot" , as.character(Sys.Date()) , ".png"), width=600, height=350)`

Comment: Thank you, that solved the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1)** Use one of these producing the forms shown in the comments above the code:

```
# plot-2021-04-13.png
filename <- sprintf("plot-%s.png", Sys.Date())

# plot-20210413.png
filename <- format(Sys.Date(), "plot-%Y%m%d.png")
```

**2)** or if there can be multiple files on the same date and you want to distinguish them by using the time use this which produces the form shown in the comment above the code:

```
# plot-20210413-090404.png
filename <- format(Sys.time(), "plot-%Y%m%d-%H%M%S.png")
```

**3)** Instead of the time one could use a form such as plot-2021-04-13-001.png where the last three digits are a sequence number for files produced today.  This reads the filenames produced today using dir and then extracts the sequence number of the largest, increments it by 1 and then uses the corresponding filename.  We assume that the program does not cross days.

```
filenames <- dir(pattern = stem)
seqno <- if (length(filenames) == 0) 0 else 
  as.numeric(sub(".*-(...).png", "\\1", max(filenames)))
filename <- sprintf("plot-%s-%03d.png", Sys.Date(), seqno + 1)
```

**4)** If all the filenames are produced by the same program and it does not cross days it is possible to simplify (3) by just keeping track of the last seqno used so that one does not have to read the filenames.

```
stem <- sprintf("plot-%s", Sys.Date())

seqno <- 1
filename <- sprintf("%s-%03d.png", stem, seqno)
# generate plot

seqno <- seqno + 1
filename <- sprintf("%s-%03d.png", stem, seqno)
# generate plot

# ..etc...
```